# PlotOnStaticMap error: Error in points$Tile[, "X"] : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, rgooglemaps

I have always used `PlotOnStaticMap` command to add points to Google Maps plot, but with this code

```
RangeVenetoLon<-c(10.58, 13.13)
RangeVenetoLat<-c(44.75, 46.71)
MapVeneto<-GetMap.bbox(lonR=RangeVenetoLon, latR=RangeVenetoLat, size = c(640,640),MINIMUMSIZE=T)
PlotOnStaticMap(MapVeneto,lon=xVeneto,lat=yVeneto, FUN = points, pch=16,col="blue")
```

I've found

```
Error in points$Tile[, "X"] : subscript out of bounds
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Please provide your `xVeneto` and `yVeneto` objects.

Comment: Here's Dropbox public link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47720440/Stackoverflow.RData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xVeneto` and `yVeneto` objects appear to be `matrix` objects, when standard `vector`s are needed. This works:

```
    PlotOnStaticMap(MapVeneto,lon=xVeneto[,1],lat=yVeneto[,1], FUN = points, pch=16,col="blue")
```